# Disallow linking objects based on a rule

Tags: django, api, django-admin, authorization, django-rest-framework

I have two models: `Domain` and `Record`. Many records link to a domain. The domains and records have their owners. I want to disallow users to create records in domains that they don't own. However they should be able to edit records if someone else (a superuser e.g.) created them and set owner to that specific user (even if they don't own a domain). This should work both for admin site and for API (rest_framework)

My question is - what is the simplest way to achieve this goal? Is there some django plugin that handles permissions for linking? Can I use model validators here (if so - how to distinguish if a new object is created)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the Django Rest Framework and Django itself (via admin) are interacting only at the level of the models. In order to achieve your goal I would implement the following design:

- Make the models aware of their owners and users. For that I would use [django-audit-log](http://django-audit-log.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).
- Overwrite the default model Manager and build your logic in the create method, where I will query the user's attributes and throw appropriate exceptions.

Such a design shifts some of the business logic from the controller to the data model - there are some debates out there about the benefits and pitfalls of such an approach. But with the underlined constraints (Django admin and API) is the only common place where you could put it.

Is this what you are aiming for ?